# What is the best way to prevent IllegalStateException during fragment transactions before onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my project I'm using only a single Activity and all the screens are implemented by fragments. My `Activity` just controls `fragment` navigation, permission handling, showing alert dialogues and such things. 
I frequently come across this situation. The issue is , In all the above mentioned cases, Like requesting for permission, showing alerts etc, `Activity` and `Fragment` will go to `onPause` and if immediately after this operations if I'm going to another screen, which means immediately if I execute `Fragment Transaction`, the `Activity` would still be in the `onPause` state and it will cause a crash. I have to wait till `Activity` comes to `resume` state. 
One use case is , in the splash screen I'm asking permissions. After asking permissions , if allowed I have to launch home screen, which is another fragment. So the very next code to be executed after permission call back is a fragment transaction , and since it will take some time by the activity to come back to `resume` because of the permission asking `dialog` had come on top of `Activity`, I have to wait for sometime to execute `fragment transaction`.

Same is the case when `onActivityResult` happens.
Currently I'm doing a quick fix for that. I'm keeping a runnable as member in Activity which is the fragment transaction runnable. And I'll try catch an `IllegalStateException` and in the `catch` I'm assigning the fragment transaction to the Runnable. And Everytime in the Activity `onResume` if the Runnable is not null I'm just executing it.
Same fix for `onActivityResult` also. the result I will keep in a member and deliver to the fragment in `onResume` of Activity. 
But I don't think it's a good practice. The code looks ugly as well because of the use of so many members in Activity just to deal with this error. 
Is there any good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this problem by committing the fragment transaction with state loss

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                      .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new Fragment())
                      .commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

But if you want to retain the state of the fragment, you shouldn't do fragment transaction after `onSaveInstanceState` is called.